# Why does a resolution of 3008x1692 look clearer than each smaller until to 3840x2160?

Tags: macbook-pro

Today I discovered, that on my Dell 43 Ultra HD 4K Multi-Client Monitor P4317Q, the resolution between 3008x1692 to 3840x2160, looks terrible, not clear, has torn font, etc.

Why on a resolution below or equal to 3008x1692 fonts look very good, and clear? Can anybody explain it? Is it a bug on macOS?

Comment: What connector are you using -- e.g. DisplayPort, HDMI... ? Have you tried a different one? Are you actually changing the resolution, or changing the scaled resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Your monitor has a pixel density of 102 pixels per inch. MacOS is 'optimized' for Hi-DPI displays with densities of over 160ppi. (Retina displays are between 220 and 260ppi.)

MacOS no longer includes 'sub-pixel' rendering, which is needed to make low-density display look good. (There is a performance penalty in using it on hi-dpi displays, where it's unnecessary.)

If you've found a setting where the display looks good, then I would use it.